# Flexible long wire for high currents

Tags: current, atx, flexible

I have an ATX power supply which has got multiple 5v outputs (at a maximum 40 amp current). I am willing to use it to power up a moving mechanical system 5-10 meters away. The problem is that since the current can be so high I need a thick wire which obviously lacks flexibility. I am looking for a way to "carry" the low voltage high current through a() flexible, long but relatively lossless cable(s).

The ATX splits up the outputs to avoid thick wires into multiple 5v header pins.

Should I do something similar? ; split the supply into multiple cables?

I was also thinking of carrying high voltage low current but I find voltage regulators with huge current outputs to be very rare and rather expensive.

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power companies get around it by increasing the voltage and decreasing the current.  There's nothing you can do to reduce the total gauge of wire needed to transfer a given current, but if you can reduce that current then you can reduce the total gauge needed.

Instead of feeding the 5V direct from the ATX supply you could consider feeding 12V from the ATX supply instead - you could then halve the current requirement for transmission.  On your remote device you can then use smaller light weight switching regulators (obviously rated for the right currents) to convert it to a higher current 5V supply.

Even better if you could ditch the ATX supply and use a slightly higher voltage, say 24V or 48V, which you then regulate down with switching regulators in your remote device.

Answer (score 1):

I would just extend the existing cables one by one.  Using the same gauge as the existing cable may lead to a high voltage drop over this distance, so you should look for thicker cables (or splice e.g. one existing wire to two extension cables). This is simple math.

However, it also depends on your needs for flexibility and characteristics of the supply. An extension of the mains and placing your supply on your mechanical system may also be an option as it needs no soldering and the power cord is quite flexible.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to put the supply remotely and use mains voltage through a flexible cable. An affordable remote regulator of similar rating is unlikely to be much lighter (not counting the housing). You can use 240V input, so a high voltage drop in the cable would be of little consequence.

Alternatively, look at finely stranded 'noodle' wire, which is very flexible (though you can't escape the weight for a given cross-sectional area, and thus voltage drop over a given length at the operating current).

Comment: The ATX itself weighs a lot hence I am trying to avoid placing it onto the system

Comment: Moving the ATX supply as near as possible is definitely the best (and "right") thing to do. Maybe @Gabe you can go a bit deeper in explaining your system? Maybe you need that much current on the end effector of a robotic arm, so you can't really strap the ATX on it. The more details you give, the better answer you get.